# Angularjs onBlur and jQuery onBlur execute in wrong order

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onblur

I have a directive on an element that defined an onblur function.  The same element also defines an ng-blur in the html

The issue is that the two function execute in the 'wrong' order.

Is there a way to control this?

Comment: You could try setting [priority](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-) of your directive

Comment: I corrected the question - its a directive and an ng-blur that I defined.  When I had my own blur directive it worked in the order I wanted (directive blur first, then MY blur).  But now the ng-blur executes before the directive defined blur.

Comment: OK, setting prioirty to -1 worked.  The default is 0, which must be what ng-blur uses

Comment: I would think you would need to set *higher* priority for that to work

Comment: Thats what doc says, but "higher" priority with numerics is ambiguous.  1 comes before 2, comes before 3, etc... in most priority systems, which makes it a shame that the default is 0.  Its NOT intuitive